# How to create a mixed development pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Excuse me because I can't include code because this situation faced me in work and for some security reasons I can't share code.

### What I have:

I have an Objective-c pod contains UI components and major base classes

### I want to:

I want to use a Swift component (RatePlanCardView) in the main project.
I need when to create a view controller contains view with custom class (RatePlanCardView) and create an outlet for it, I can call any function in this custom class.

### What I did:

I created a view controller in a storyboard contains view, then I changed the class of this view to be (RatePlanCardView) and created an outlet for it.

### What happened:

When I followed the debug, I found that the class of this outlet is UIView not (RatePlanCardView) so every call of any function in custom class error happened like below.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView adjustCardView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffbae08ab10'

While (adjustCardView) is function in (RatePlanCardView) class.

### I had 2 solutions:

1- I created Swift pod for the new component (RatePlanCardView) and this class inherits a class from ObjC pod (ExpandableCardView) and it compiles successfully. When I put the new pod in the main project and use it as I need everything compiles successfully but when I navigate to my new view controller and call the function (adjustCardView) the error above fires. but When I see the definition of this function xCode move me to the right function but it can't execute any function because it already sees the custom class as UIView, not RatePlanCardView.

2- I tried to search for, how to create mixed developed pod but I couldn't find any support of tutorial for this solution.

### Note:

Thanks for your patience and support and giving me your time to read my issues.
Of course, any other solution will be more than welcome. Also if you helped me with any above solution also thanks.

Thanks in advance.

### I solved this issue:

I created framework containing objC code and swift code with bridging header file and everything worked just fine

Comment: Please double check that the UIView has been correctly set to a RatePlanCardView in the Identity Inspector. If it has then I would delete the outlet in the Connections Inspector and try again.

Comment: @Magnas I will try and tell you, thanks

Comment: @Magnas I tried and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

The outlet you created should be something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet RatePlanCardView *rpCardViewOutlet;
```

Now go to XIB and connect this outlet with your `RatePlanCardView` view. This way you can only connect view with outlet if the type matches and any call to function of this class should fire.

Comment: It should but this doesn't happen. What happened is Xcode sees this outlet of type UIView, not of type RatePlanCardView